# LogStash dissect with key=value, comma

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have a pattern of logs that contain performance&statistical data. I have configured LogStash to dissect this data as csv format in order to save the values to ES.

`<1>,www1,3,BISTATS,SCAN,330,712.6,2035,17.3,221.4,656.3`

I am using the following LogSTash filter and getting the desired results..

```
grok {
  match => { "Message" => "\A<%{POSINT:priority}>,%{DATA:pan_host},%{DATA:pan_serial_number},%{DATA:pan_type},%{GREEDYDATA:message}\z" }
  overwrite => [ "Message" ]
}
csv {
  separator => ","
  columns => ["pan_scan","pf01","pf02","pf03","kk04","uy05","xd06"]
}
```

This is currently working well for me as long as the order of the columns doesn't get messed up.

However I want to make this logfile more meaningful and have each column-name in the original log. example-- `<1>,www1,30000,BISTATS,SCAN,pf01=330,pf02=712.6,pf03=2035,kk04=17.3,uy05=221.4,xd06=656.3`

This way I can keep inserting or appending key/values in the middle of the process without corrupting the data. (Using LogStash5.3)

Comment: Instead of grok, which is way too brittle for this, use the [csv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html). And for key-value pairs, use the [kv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using @baudsp recommendations, I was able to formulate the following. I deleted the `csv{}` block completely and replace it with the `kv{}` block. The `kv{}` automatically created all the key values leaving me to only `mutate{}` the fields into floats and integers.

```
 json {
  source => "message"
  remove_field => [ "message", "headers" ]
 }
 date {
   match => [ "timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" ]
   target => "timestamp"
 }
 grok {
   match => { "Message" => "\A<%{POSINT:priority}>,%{DATA:pan_host},%{DATA:pan_serial_number},%{DATA:pan_type},%{GREEDYDATA:message}\z" }
   overwrite => [ "Message" ]
 }
 kv {
  allow_duplicate_values => false
  field_split_pattern => ","
 }
```

Using the above block, I was able to insert the K=V, pairs anywhere in the message. Thanks again for all the help. I have added a sample code block for anyone trying to accomplish this task.

Note: I am using NLog for logging, which produces JSON outputs. From the C# code, the format looks like this.

```
var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.ExtendedInfo("<1>,www1,30000,BISTATS,SCAN,pf01=330,pf02=712.6,pf03=2035,kk04=17.3,uy05=221.4,xd06=656.3");
```